# How to add data to db via webform

Tags: mysql, webforms

I'm PHP and MySQL novice.

I take base code to add entries to a db from http://smallbusiness.chron.com/transfer-data-form-database-46976.html and I do the following:

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `autos` (
  `CIID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Anio` text,
  `Marca` text,
  `Tipo` text,
  `Modelo` text,
  `Color` text,
  `Descripcion` text,

  PRIMARY KEY (`CIID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `autos` (`CIID`, `Anio`, `Marca`, `Tipo`, `Modelo`, `Color`, `Descripcion`)  VALUES

('1', '2008', 'VW', 'Auto', 'Jetta', 'Azul', ''),
('2', '2008', 'Chevrolet', 'Auto', 'Cobalt', 'Blanco', ''),
('3', '2006', 'Chevrolet', 'Auto', 'Cobalt', 'Gris', ''),
('4', '2001', 'Chevrolet', 'Suv', 'Avalanche', 'Azul', ''),
('5', '1999', 'Chevrolet', 'Auto', 'Camaro', 'Azul', '');
```

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<b>Añadir Registro:</b>
<form action=add.php method=”post”>
<table border=0>
<tr><td>
    Año
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Anio[]" size="20">
</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>
    Marca
</td><td valign=top>
    <select name="Marca[]" class="dropdown">
        <option value="">Selecciona Marca</option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
        <option value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</option>
        <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="Bentley">Bentley</option>
        ...
    </select>
</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>
    Tipo
</td><td valign=top>
    <select name="Tipo[]" class="dropdown">
        <option value="">Selecciona Tipo</option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Moto">Moto</option>
        <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
        <option value="Minivan">Minivan</option>
        ...
    </select>
</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>
    Modelo
</td><td valign=top>
    <input type="text" name="Modelo[]" size="20">
</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>
    Color
</td><td valign=top>
    <input type="text" name="Color[]" size="20">
</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>
    Descripción
</td><td valign=top>
    <textarea name="Descripcion[]" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>

</td><td valign=top>
    <input type=submit value="Añadir">
</form>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

add.php:

```
<?php
     $connect = mysql_connect(“localhost”, “high_pipo”, “*****”);
     if (!connect) { die('Connection Failed: ' . mysql_error());
     { mysql_select_db(“high_pipo”, $connect);
     $user_info = “INSERT INTO `autos` (CIID, Anio, Marca, Tipo, Modelo, Color, Descripcion) VALUES ('75', '$_POST[Anio]',
 '$_POST[Marca]', '$_POST[Tipo]', '$_POST[Modelo]', '$_POST[Color]',
 '$_POST[Descripcion]')”;
     if (!mysql_query($user_info, $connect)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     echo “Your information was added to the database.”;
     mysql_close($connect); ?>
```

And I got following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING) in /home/high/public_html/masautos/administracion/add.php on line 5

How can I fix this?
Additionally how define first field (CIID) as autoincrement on add.php or on index.php as is marked on db?

Comment: You're using wrong quotes. Replace ” with "

Answer (score 0):

If in your database ciid is marked as autoincrement then you don't need it in your insert.
Also try to not use mysql_query any more. Prepared statements is a better approach.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database_name', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `autos` (`Anio`, `Marca`, `Tipo`, `Modelo`, `Color`, `Descripcion`) VALUES (:anio, :marca, :tipo, :modelo, :color, :descripcion)");
$stmt->bindParam(':anio', $_POST['Anio']);
$stmt->bindParam(':marca', $_POST['Marca']);
$stmt->bindParam(':tipo', $_POST['Tipo']);
$stmt->bindParam(':modelo', $_POST['Modelo']);
$stmt->bindParam(':color', $_POST['Color']);
$stmt->bindParam(':descripcion', $_POST['Descripcion']);
$stmt->execute();
```

in case you use indexes or primary keys in 1 or 2 or more fields of this table then you could use insert ... on duplicate key update as shown in this tutorial http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
If you want to keep an error log in your queries then you could include them in a try-catch statement and you could write the errors on a txt file in your applications root directory.
to close database connection use

```
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter, now no errors and a new consecutive numbered row (CIID) is added, but all other new data are empty (NULL).

Comment: Are your data ($_POST[Anio],$_POST[Marca],...,$_POST[Descripcion]) being posted? Also for better performance change to InnoDB. ALTER TABLE `autos` ENGINE=InnoDB;